# java.lang.StackOverflowError when java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:569)

Tags: java, performance, javaagents, contextclassloader

I have these filling up in the catalina log file causing disk space issues when javaagent is attached. I have no idea from where there are getting triggered. What could be the reason ?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1541)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:668)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:569)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
...........
```

Comment: Exact java version?

Comment: 1.8.0_275 and saw this on 11.0.10 also. So i think its not about version. I am using URLClassloader and trying to load the class. This cannot happen until the current classloader is parent to itself. I am clearly setting the current context classloader as the parent. Any thoughts ?

Comment: The version is important to make sense of the line number.

Comment: Looks like this is Java 11: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#L576. What java agent is attached?

Comment: This is an interesting question. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.